# How to zoom worksheet in Excel with Office.js API?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I'm trying to zoom an excel worksheet with Office.js.
I tried this `worksheet.zoom = { scale: 200};`  Unfortunately it didn't work

```js
Excel.run(function (context) {
    var worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    worksheet.zoom = {scale: 200};

    return context.sync();
}).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

I want to chang the scale like this: [image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid Worksheet didn't have property: zoom based on the doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview. And currently we didn't have API to change zoom settings on worksheet.

We track Office Add-in feature requests on our [UserVoice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 0):

See here --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pagelayout?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-pagelayout-zoom-member

```
// Link to full sample: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/prod/samples/excel/54-worksheet/worksheet-page-layout.yaml
await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const farmSheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Print");
    farmSheet.pageLayout.zoom = { scale: 200 };
    await context.sync();
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3649