# How to Use Javascript in the Excel Web Add-In Application to Zoom the Current Excel WorkSheet

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins, office-2016, excel-online

I am trying to increase Zoom for my Excel Online file using my Add-In. I am using the below javascript code but getting error as "**GeneralException: An internal error has occurred.**"

Please advise where am I going wrong. Online tutorials not much of help with this generic error.

```
Excel.run(function (context) {
    const worksheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    const worksheet = worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

    if (worksheet) {
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                worksheet.pageLayout.zoom = { scale: 200 };
            });
    } 
}).catch(function (error) {
    $('#txtcount').val(error);
    console.error(error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.error("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        $('#txtcount2').val("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Comment: Please reproduce the problem in the [Script Lab tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab). Export a gist of your code and provide the URL of the gist. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. We are investigating it. Internal tracking number: 8589150.

Comment: Thanks @penglongzhaochina for the investiation. Look forward to your response further :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to zoom worksheet in Excel with Office.js API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65323903/how-to-zoom-worksheet-in-excel-with-office-js-api)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73044578/5079799

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3649

Answer (score 0):

After do some investigation, I think the API works well. I think the issue may cause by some "async" issue. Below is the code can work, please try it:

```
const worksheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
const worksheet = worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

worksheet.pageLayout.load('zoom');
await context.sync();
console.log(worksheet.pageLayout.zoom);
worksheet.pageLayout.zoom = { scale: 200 };
await context.sync();
worksheet.pageLayout.load('zoom');
await context.sync();
console.log(worksheet.pageLayout.zoom);
```

Feel free to contact me if you have other questions.